# Why don't prefixed calls work on access types?

Tags: ada

I have some methods in a package that operate on an access constant tot a tagged record; in order to call these functions, I must specify the package name. I would much rather just put the variable name [dot] function name, but this gives the error: `no selector "foo" for type "Color"`. Why is that?

Here's a minimal reproducer:

```vhdl
procedure Main is

  type Color is tagged
    record
      Hue : Integer;
      Saturation : Integer;
      Value : Integer;
    end record;

  type AccessColor is access constant Color;

  procedure foo (C : in AccessColor) is
  begin
    null;
  end foo;

  AccessS : AccessColor;

begin
  foo (AccessS);
  --AccessS.foo; -- does not work. Why?
end Main;
```

Note that in my real code, it is inconvenient to specify the function fully, because unlike in the example above, foo is defined somewhere in a seperate package:

```ada
Some.Package.Name.Depp.foo(AccessS);
```

Even though AccessS already specifies where to find the function, so I should just be able to do:

```vhdl
AccessS.foo;
```

Comment: Just a note: Objects of tagged types are always passed by reference, so if your goal is to avoid copying the object, there is no need to define `foo` on an access type. It can also take `in Color` for the same result.

Comment: Why are you using access types? They're almost never needed. They certainly don't appear to be needed for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `foo` isn’t actually a primitive operation of `Color` (in this reproducer).

[ARM 3.3.2(6)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-3-2-3.html#p6) says that the primitive subprograms of a specific type are

> For a specific type **declared immediately within a package_specification**, any subprograms (in addition to the enumeration literals) that are **explicitly declared immediately within the same package_specification** and that operate on the type

This (apologies for reformatting, casing adjustment) compiles fine.

```ada
procedure Main is

   package Pak is

      type Color is tagged
         record
            Hue : Integer;
            Saturation : Integer;
            Value : Integer;
         end record;

      procedure Foo (C : in Color) is null;

      type AccessColor is access constant Color;

   end Pak;

   Col : aliased Pak.Color;

   AccessS : Pak.AccessColor := Col'Access;

begin
   AccessS.Foo;
end Main;
```

I declared `Foo` as taking `in Color`; you could equally declare it to take `access constant Color` if you need to, because ([ARM 4.1.3(9.2)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-4-1-3.html#p9.2))

> The first formal parameter of the subprogram shall be of type T, or a class-wide type that covers T, or an access parameter designating one of these types

Answer (score 5):

This doesn't work because as you define it, `foo` is not a *primitive operation* of the tagged type `Color`. Prefix notation can only be used on primitive operations of tagged types.

The solution is to make `foo` a primitive operation of `Color` like this:

```vhdl
procedure foo (C : access constant Color) is
begin
   null;
end foo;
```

If you use a named access type, `foo` will instead be a primitive operation of that type, and since that type is not a tagged type, prefix notation doesn't work.

Comment: after changing the function definition to specify `access constant Color` as the parameter, I still get the same error in the commented usage line.

Comment: You may need to define `AccessS` accordingly. I am unsure whether defining the type `AccessColor` causes type freezing – it shouldn't afair but try moving it below the procedure.